# Creating UIcollectionView with Waterfall layout and self sizing cell

Tags: swift3, uicollectionview, ios9, ios10, uicollectionviewlayout

I am trying to implement waterfallLayout with a self sizing cell that should work with iOS >= 9.0
Something like pintrest collectionViewLayout not the transition but the difference is that i have a fixed ratio of image but fields below is dynamic which i used `UIStackView`.

[image]
  The self sizing is working fine but my problem is in changing the cell origin to be always = 15 PX between cells.

so when i tried FlowLayout without any customisation everything is working fine except for the margins between cells is not correct but the scrolling is working well without any performance issue for iOS >= 9.0

After trying CustomizingFlowLayout the performance is so bad in iOS 10 things is not working while in iOS 9 works fine. i know that apple did some improvement with the UICollectionView but with me i don't see that improvement.

My Cell:

```
 override func preferredLayoutAttributesFitting(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {
    self.setNeedsLayout()
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
    layoutAttributes.bounds.size.height = systemLayoutSizeFitting(layoutAttributes.size, withHorizontalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriorityRequired, verticalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriorityFittingSizeLevel).height
    return layoutAttributes
}
```

My controller:

```
ViewDidLoad {
  layoutView = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! CustomLayout
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            self.collectionView.isPrefetchingEnabled = false
        }
        layoutView.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width:      layoutView.cellWidth, height: 200)
 }

extension RecipesCollectionWithSortBar: UICollectionViewDataSource {
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return array.count
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: customCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! customCell
    return cell
}
 extension RecipesCollectionWithSortBar : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.bounds.maxY == scrollView.contentSize.height &&  !isLoadingMoreRecipes {
       //
        LoadMore
    }
  }
```

My CustomFlowLayout

```
    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        let attrs = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)
        var attrsCopy = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

        for element in attrs! where (element.copy() as! UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes).representedElementCategory == .cell
            && element.frame.height != cacheCells[element.indexPath.item]?.frame.height {
            if element.indexPath.item == 0 {
                element.frame.origin.y = self.sectionInset.top
                element.frame.origin.x = self.sectionInset.left
            } else if element.indexPath.item == 1 {
                element.frame.origin.y = self.sectionInset.top
                element.frame.origin.x = cacheCells[0]!.frame.maxX + margin
            } else {
                let previous = cacheCells[element.indexPath.item - 2]
                element.frame.origin.y = previous!.frame.maxY + self.minimumInteritemSpacing
                element.frame.origin.x = previous!.frame.origin.x
            }
            cacheCells[element.indexPath.item] = element
            attrsCopy.append(element)
        }

        let values = cacheCells.values.filter({ $0.frame.intersects(rect) })
        return values.map({ $0 })
    }
```

Here i have many problems :
 1- i have a huge white space at the end of the collectionView because i changed the cell origin this problem only happens at iOS > 10.
 i tried to override the content size

```
func getContentHeight() -> CGFloat {
        if !cacheCells.values.isEmpty {
            let attribute = cacheCells.values.max { $0.0.frame.maxY < $0.1.frame.maxY }
            return attribute!.frame.maxY + sectionInset.bottom
        }
        return contHeight
    }
    override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: self.cellWidth * CGFloat(columnCount), height: getContentHeight())
    }
```

for some reason iOS 9 don't like this solution the scroll stops ..

2- Scrolling performance is so bad in iOS 10 and worst in iOS 9.0.

3- when i load more believe it or not it scroll 3 or 4 times and doesn't have more items to show when i print the log (i have 100 item but the collection view show only 70) and sometimes when hard scrolling it remembers that there's some more items and show them. i am not sure what i am doing wrong.

It's been 2 weeks now trying to figure out what's wrong may be having some fresh eye and mind can point on the problem i am having.

Comment: that is not a self-sizing cell, but a custom transition between two view controllers.

Comment: i don't mean on clicking on the cell, i mean in the collectionViewLayout the spacing between cells